# How to import .dat file?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to import faminc99.dat in the zip file faminc99.dat.Z on the NBER website: http://data.nber.org/psid/supp/

However, I tried `read.table`, `read.delim` and used several different `sep`, and always got only 1 variable in the data imported. I'm not sure about the reason. Can anyone shed light on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to *@sindri_baldur*'s answer, use the `faminc_99.zip` file which includes the same `faminc99.dat`. The advantage is you may directly process the file in R.

The `widths=` are different, and to find out the values without codebook is a little forensic, but there's actually the information `"Width:"` in your linked codebook! We can also open `faminc99.dat` in a text editor and create a representative row with the given 48 distinguishable values to get a vector `x`,

```
x <- c("06933"," 4"," 2"," 213800.0"," 200000.0"," 13800","     0","    0","    0","     0","xyrid","      0","htdck","      0","      0","     0","      0","0","0","0","     0","     0","xyrid","     0","asgnd","    0","xscid","    0","xscid","     0","asgnd","     0","asgnd","    0","asgnd","    0","asgnd","     0","asgnd","200000","asgnd","  0","  0"," 45"," 69"," 2667"," 0915"," 4.197")
```

which character lengths we can count unsing `nchar`,

```
wdt <- nchar(x)
```

which gives us the desired widths `wdt`  that we may plug into `read.fwf`.

```
## lk <- "http://data.nber.org/psid/supp/faminc99.dat.Z"  ## unknown .Z archive
lk <- "http://data.nber.org/psid/supp/faminc_99.zip"

temp <- tempfile()  ## open connection

download.file(lk, temp)
r <- read.fwf(unz(temp, "faminc99.dat"), wdt)

unlink(temp)  ## close connection
```

In the string variables there are elements with just spaces that we might want to turn into `NA`. (I think `r[sapply(r, is.character)]` isn't absolutely necessary here).

```
r[] <- lapply(r, function(z) {z[grep("^\\s*$", z)] <- NA;z})
```

### Result

```
head(r)
#    V1 V2 V3    V4    V5   V6    V7 V8    V9 V10  V11  V12  V13 V14 V15  V16  V17
# 1  1 19 14 25500 25500    0     0  0     0   0 <NA>    0 <NA>   0   0    0    0
# 2  2 47 41 27060 22260 4800     0  0     0   0 <NA>    0 <NA>   0   0    0    0
# 3  3 47 41 11718     0 5400     0  0  6318   0 <NA>    0 <NA>   0   0    0    0
# 4  4 26 21 73928 73428  500     0  0     0   0 <NA> 7114 <NA>   0   0 3557 3557
# 5  5 37 32 32760 19000 4800     0  0  8960   0 <NA>    0 <NA>   0   0    0    0
# 6  6 29 24 30430  3000 3940 11085  0 12405   0 <NA>    0 <NA>   0   0    0    0
#   V18 V19 V20   V21   V22  V23 V24  V25 V26  V27 V28  V29 V30  V31 V32  V33 V34
# 1   0   0   0 25000 25000 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0
# 2   0   0   0 20900 20800 <NA> 100 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0
# 3   0   0   0     0     0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0
# 4   1   0   1 56970 56970 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0
# 5   0   0   0     0     0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0
# 6   0   0   0     0     0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>   0
#    V35 V36  V37 V38  V39   V40  V41 V42 V43 V44 V45  V46   V47    V48
# 1 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>     0 <NA> 430  69   0   0 1922  8480 25.278
# 2 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>  1360 <NA> 310 628 663 319 4087 17088 18.344
# 3 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>     0 <NA>   0   0   0   0 2338  9344 25.921
# 4 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>  9344 <NA> 152 219 281 339 4283 19453 15.649
# 5 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA> 15000 <NA>   0   0 372 857 2476  9853 34.565
# 6 <NA>   0 <NA>   0 <NA>     0 <NA>   0   0   0   0 6360 27715  5.825
```

**Where**

```
str(r)
# 'data.frame': 6997 obs. of  48 variables:
#   $ V1 : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
# $ V2 : int  19 47 47 26 37 29 6 8 39 45 ...
# $ V3 : int  14 41 41 21 32 24 4 5 34 39 ...
# $ V4 : num  25500 27060 11718 73928 32760 ...
# $ V5 : num  25500 22260 0 73428 19000 ...
# $ V6 : int  0 4800 5400 500 4800 3940 0 200 0 0 ...
# $ V7 : int  0 0 0 0 0 11085 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V8 : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V9 : int  0 0 6318 0 8960 12405 0 0 8760 0 ...
# $ V10: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V11: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
# $ V12: int  0 0 0 7114 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V13: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
# $ V14: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V15: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V16: int  0 0 0 3557 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V17: int  0 0 0 3557 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V18: int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V19: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V20: int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V21: int  25000 20900 0 56970 0 0 34000 24825 0 34500 ...
# $ V22: int  25000 20800 0 56970 0 0 28000 24825 0 34500 ...
# $ V23: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
# $ V24: int  0 100 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V25: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
# $ V26: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V27: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
# $ V28: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V29: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
# $ V30: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V31: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
# $ V32: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 3000 0 0 0 ...
# $ V33: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
# $ V34: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V35: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
# $ V36: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 3000 0 0 0 ...
# $ V37: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
# $ V38: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V39: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
# $ V40: int  0 1360 0 9344 15000 0 0 0 0 0 ...
# $ V41: chr  NA NA NA NA ...
# $ V42: int  430 310 0 152 0 0 706 14 0 133 ...
# $ V43: int  69 628 0 219 0 0 398 187 0 858 ...
# $ V44: int  0 663 0 281 372 0 984 0 0 0 ...
# $ V45: int  0 319 0 339 857 0 769 0 0 0 ...
# $ V46: int  1922 4087 2338 4283 2476 6360 2667 2932 1648 3268 ...
# $ V47: int  8480 17088 9344 19453 9853 27715 10915 13120 7818 16246 ...
# $ V48: num  25.3 18.3 25.9 15.6 34.6 ...
```

Comment: Thanks! How did you know there are 30 variables? By the codebook: http://data.nber.org/psid/supp/famcbk99.htm, there should be 48 variables in total. Also, can we recover those variables' names?

Comment: @tobinz There is some code for SAS and SPSS which you can use to find the variable names and their order.

Comment: @tobinz Thanks for the hint with 48 variables, in the codebook there's the `Width` information for each variable, so you may create a vector out of it. Also Variable name information is there. You may use copy-paste or use web-scraping.

Answer (score 1):

It is fixed-width text file which you should be able to read with `read.fwf()`:

```
df <- read.fwf("faminc99.dat", widths = rep(9,27)) # Note these widths are wrong
```

Comment: It's `rep(9, 30)`, isn't it? +1 though, didn't knew `read.fwf` yet. See my additional answer.

Comment: @jay.sf If I remember correctly each row was 243 or 9*27 characters wide. But maybe they are not all 9 characters wide. It was a wild guess that seemed to work. Might be wrong.

Comment: Seems we both were wrong, the widths are different, OP linked the codebook with width information included in a comment under my answer.